# Creating Shape by Density Criteria using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a map with points plotted.

Is there a way that I can make a circle of a certain radius (let's assume 10 miles) if the density of points in any given 10 mile radius is over a certain number?

Answer (score 1):

I hoped to answer in precise and straightforward manner as the question, but only I could think of a `Virtual Layer` approach.

With a test sample (`my_points` layer) of 1,000 points scattered around 16 km x 10 km area, this syntax:

```
SELECT x.ID AS ID, x.count AS COUNT, st_buffer(x.geometry, 1609.3) AS geometry
FROM
  (SELECT a.id AS ID, Count(b.id) AS count, a.geometry AS geometry
   FROM my_points a CROSS JOIN my_points b
   ON  a.id != b.id AND (st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) < 1609.3)
   GROUP BY a.id
   ORDER BY a.id) x
WHERE x.count/pi() > 20     -- if greater then 20 points per miles^2
```

returned an output image below.

[image]

- When you use this for your data, change the layer "**my_points**" in the fourth line `FROM` **my_points** `a CROSS JOIN` **my_points** `b` to your layer name.
- As my CRS was on UTM in meters, I used conversion rate 1609.3 (meter/mile) so the radius of each circle is 1 miles (...though you asked for 10 miles, sorry).
- I used the density threshold at 20 points per square miles. Please adjust it as necessary.